# LocalDateTime - преобразование в секунды

Tags: java

Как преобразовать объект класса `LocalDateTime` в секунды, и так чтобы поместилось в какой-то тип данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` не содержит информации о временной зоне. Так просто в лоб не получить секунды из этого объекта

Как вариант, зная временную зону, можно получить объект `ZonedDateTime` с привязкой к зоне, а уже из него получить секунды.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow"));
long sec = zoneDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli()/1000;
```